# Pentaho 8 CDE : find components source code for sample

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to create my own custom components for Pentaho CDE.

- Where I can find source code of simple component buttons/grid inside Pentaho 8.X solution ? (inside project directory) ?
- How to find source code sample on web ?

Thanks
Nico

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search could've answered this.

The source code for all the Pentaho community editions is on GitHub:
https://github.com/pentaho

For the dashboards, you're likely to end up using the Community Dashboard components. They are also on GitHub: https://github.com/webdetails